# Convert SCSS to SASS for Neat grid

Tags: sass, grid, neat

I am using SASS for styling with Neat
But the tutorial is based on SCSS.
Both are quite new to me. 
I don't really know how to convert the SCSS code below to SASS.

```css
$my-custom-grid: (
  columns: 12,
  gutter: 20px,
  media: 1200px,
  color: rgba(#00d4ff, 0.25),
  direction: ltr,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your example, the SASS version would be like this

```
$my-custom-grid: (columns: 12, gutter: 20px, media: 1200px, color: rgba(#00d4ff, 0.25), direction: ltr)
```

All on one line and no ; at the end

A good way to convert is to go to [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) and start out with the options saying its SCSS, then select SASS in the options